# Dell Inspiron 1564 overheating but fan not switching on, how to diagnose?

Tags: fan, cooling, temperature, dell-inspiron

I've got a Dell Inspiron 1564 laptop that is about one and a half years old. Since about a week, the laptop started to overheat, causing it to switch off unexpectedly...

The cpu fan is working erratically, it can start to spin for a while, doing its job and cooling down the cpu before it stops, but then the temperature goes up, and the fan doesn't reacts, once the temperature reaches a critical point (over 85 celsius, checked with speedfan...), the laptop switches off...

I already cleaned the vents and fan from dust, to no avail, and it was actually quite clean anyway.

Drivers and bios are up-to-date, no crapware was ever installed on this machine.

I don't know how to diagnose the problem, could it be the temperature sensors that sends wrong information, so the fan doesn't reacts? but then I believe the computer wouldn't detect the overheat and stop...

Is there a way I can pin point the problem? Maybe some low-level diagnostic tools to check functionality of sensors and fans???

The warranty is already over so any suggestion would be welcome.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download and make the Dell diagnostic](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R260461&SystemID=INSPIRON1564&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=3841&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=13&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=382142) boot media, then boot from it and run the hardware extended tests.

.

[Dell Main page for your model](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?)

.

Comment: And the diagnostic is: "Error Code 3700:011B PROCESSOR_FAN - The fan speed is incorrect." The test didn't finish though, computer stopped again :-) . Seems I'll have to find a new fan...

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem in my Inspiron 1464. I removed the RAM and inserted again. After doing this I started my computer. The fan works well then.